# Rsync cron works but monit cron doesn't

Tags: network-monitoring

I run a 14.04 Ubuntu server. I'd like to automatically receive Monit email alerts. Typing `/usr/bin/monitcron.sh` as root all works fine manually.
I tried cron with Rsync as a test. Cron works great. But as soon as I use it for Monit, it doesn't do its job anymore except when I run it manually.

In my monitcron.sh script, there is:

```
#!/bin/bash
service monit reload
```

EDIT: I've tried `/etc/init.d/monit reload`. Same thing. This works manually but not with cron.

In my `crontab -e -u root`, I tried running:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/monitcron.sh
```

But no luck.

Any ideas or reason why the script works for Rsync and not for Monit? Thx.

EDIT: My `/var/log/syslog` shows:

```
Feb 20 21:42:01 www postfix/local[5289]: A7F742490E: to=<root@www.home>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.09/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Feb 20 21:42:01 www postfix/qmgr[1151]: A7F742490E: removed
Feb 20 21:43:01 www CRON[6074]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/monitcron.sh)
Feb 20 21:43:01 www postfix/pickup[6069]: B71782490E: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 20 21:43:01 www postfix/cleanup[5111]: B71782490E: message-id=<20170220204301.B71782490E@www.home>
Feb 20 21:43:01 www postfix/qmgr[1151]: B71782490E: from=<root@www.home>, size=603, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 20 21:43:01 www postfix/local[5289]: B71782490E: to=<root@www.home>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.12, delays=0.05/0/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Feb 20 21:43:01 www postfix/qmgr[1151]: B71782490E: removed
Feb 20 21:44:01 www CRON[6085]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/monitcron.sh)
Feb 20 21:44:01 www postfix/pickup[6069]: C79642490E: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 20 21:44:01 www postfix/cleanup[5111]: C79642490E: message-id=<20170220204401.C79642490E@www.home>
Feb 20 21:44:01 www postfix/qmgr[1151]: C79642490E: from=<root@www.home>, size=603, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 20 21:44:01 www postfix/local[5289]: C79642490E: to=<root@www.home>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.06/0/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Feb 20 21:44:01 www postfix/qmgr[1151]: C79642490E: removed
Feb 20 21:45:01 www CRON[6097]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/monitcron.sh)
Feb 20 21:45:01 www postfix/pickup[6069]: D64EA2490E: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb 20 21:45:01 www postfix/cleanup[5111]: D64EA2490E: message-id=<20170220204501.D64EA2490E@www.home>
Feb 20 21:45:01 www postfix/qmgr[1151]: D64EA2490E: from=<root@www.home>, size=603, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 20 21:45:01 www postfix/local[5289]: D64EA2490E: to=<root@www.home>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.04/0/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Feb 20 21:45:01 www postfix/qmgr[1151]: D64EA2490E: removed}
```

EDIT:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j00517Nq9uo
This video told me that if I want to run 'service apache2 reload', my script should be stored in /var/www/. It works. Previously I had tried in /usr/bin/ but didn't work. 
Now that the Apache2 script is working, the question remains: where should the Monit script ('service monit reload') be run from/stored in then?

**PROBLEM FIXED:** I was sure this was a path issue. I added the path in my script as such: 
    #!/bin/bash
    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    service monit reload

I found the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180342/running-init-d-script-produces-start-stop-daemon-not-found

Thanks to Ben Whaley for his contribution and his crew's for being around helping out.

Comment: Any errors in the logs? You don't say what OS you're running - check `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/cron.log`

Comment: I run Linux. Man, I can't figure out how to paste the code. Sorry.

Comment: Your script shows `#/bin/bash` but it must be `#!/bin/bash` or it wouldn't work on the CLI either. I suggest `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: I had mistyped this: #!/bin/bash. Not working. I then tried '#!/usr/bin/env bash'. No luck either. Something strange is going on here.

Comment: Thx Ben for your help. I'll see what I can come up with to fix this.

Comment: Could this be a path-related issue? Just an idea.

Comment: As a test, on Ubuntu Desktop, this script works well: 'service ntp restart >> /home/tim/Desktop/file.txt'. So I don't know why Ubuntu server doesn't accept 'service monit restart' or even '/etc/init.d/monit restart'.

Comment: No luck. 'service apache2 restart' is working in a script. 'service monit restart' doesn't. Same as 'service monit reload'. Monit is working manually. But no way in bash script.

Comment: If you have any ideas, please share. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Said differently, /usr/bin and /var/www don't accept my Monit script whereas they accept my other scripts.

Comment: Problem fixed. See above. Thx!